# How do I display the system's default http proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

I want to get the default system web proxy and display the resulting proxy address and port for http in a text box.

```
        IWebProxy oProxy = System.Net.WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();

        //to get default proxy settings 
        oProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        Uri targetserver = new Uri("http://www.google.com/");
        Uri proxyserver = oProxy.GetProxy(targetserver);
```

the above code in debug allows me to hover over proxysever and show all i need but i can't access the properties!

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks fine.  If you need the proxy server:

```
string proxyServerAddress = proxyserver.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: Thank you I was assigning it directly to a text box but for some reason that did not work!? but assigning it to a string first works :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.getproxy.aspx), `GetProxy` returns the proxy that was explicitly set on an HttpRequest, not the system-default proxy.

Use [WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx) to get the IE proxy setting.

Comment: I just tried his code, and it works to get the default proxy, as well.

Comment: Could you show me the code as I could not get this to work!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this just be something like:

```
Textbox1.Text = proxyserver.ToString();
```

Comment: this just returns the type and not the value :(